# How to layout a page with MVC3 Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor

I've been reading about layouts, sections, views and partial views, but I don't really know how to approach a layout like this example:

[image]

- Top bar: would be like the bar that
  Facebook have on top. I would contain
  the authentication information and
  general options and menus.
- Navigation bar: would contain
  information about where are you, and
  where can you go. Also a "search"
  box.
- Body: The actual wanted information.
- Side bar: would contain relevant
  information about what is in the
  body.
- Footer: copyright, licence and things
  like that.

*Body* would be a "View", *Sidebar* would be a "Section", *Footer* would be static HTML in the "Layout", but... what would be *Top* bar and *Navigation*?

*Top bar* is not related with anything, so I would put it as a "Partial View" in the "Layout", but I cannot do that because it has to be inside the `<body>` anyway, so when I call `@RenderBody()`, it should be rendered. Same thing with *Navigation*, it's somehow related with the body, but I'd like to separate it as an external control that runs on his own and show information depending on the information in the URL.

How should I approach this?

**UPDATE, please read:** The question **is not** about CSS and HTML, it's not about how to layout this, but how to use the Razor tools to do it, it's about Razor `RenderBody` and `PartialView`.

When I return a result from my controller, I want to return just what is marked in the picture as "body", and "side bar" as a section, I'd like to avoid repeat the top bar code. Is there a way to create a "ChildView", that inherits from "ParentView", and this from "Layout", in a way that when I return "View("ChildView") the screen is built automatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [MVC3 Music Store Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-10)

The last part of that tutorial describes how design the layout to include partial views using the Html.RenderAction() method.  Also see the Html.RenderSection() method.

Comment: Ok, I see it clear now thanks to your example. @RenderBody is not just for render the <body> tag, it renders the main child view, so I can code the body in html, put PartialViews wherever I want, and render the white filled area in the example with RenderBody.

Answer (score 10):

There is a great post about Layouts with Razor: [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx).

Basically your structure will be: 
  1) _ViewStart.cshtml (that will point to a layout and other things that all of yours views would share);
  2) A .cshtml that would be your layout, ie.: _Layout.cshtml (similar to the Site.Master webpages).

Inside _Layout.cshtml you'll put your HTML layout, like this for example:

```
<body>
    <div id="maincontainer">
        <div id="topsection">
            <div class="topbar">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <div id="logindisplay">
                    @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
                </div>                
            </div>            
            <div class="nav">
                <ul><li>Home</li></ul>
            </div>            
        </div>

        <div id="contentwrapper">
            <div id="contentcolumn">
                <div class="body">                    
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">
            <b>Side bar</b>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">Footer</div>

    </div>
</body>
```

See that I put @RenderBody() inside the div "#body", so when my controller return an ActionResult, only this div will be updated with the result.